# Next-auth provider signin and signup error

Tags: reactjs, next.js, next-auth

I am using Next.js with Next-auth github and google provider, but always faced with problem `outgoing request timed out after 3500ms` and i can't login to my dashboard. this problem happens in Local (localhost) but in production every is fine.

[next-auth][error][OAUTH_CALLBACK_ERROR]
https://next-auth.js.org/errors#oauth_callback_error outgoing request timed out after 3500ms {
error: RPError: outgoing request timed out after 3500ms
at eval (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./node_modules/openid-client/lib/helpers/request.js:115:19)
at async Client.requestResource (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./node_modules/openid-client/lib/client.js:1029:26)
at async Client.userinfo (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./node_modules/openid-client/lib/client.js:1109:26)
at async Object.request (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./node_modules/next-auth/providers/github.js:21:33)
at async oAuthCallback (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./node_modules/next-auth/core/lib/oauth/callback.js:127:23)
at async Object.callback (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./node_modules/next-auth/core/routes/callback.js:18:79)
at async AuthHandler (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./node_modules/next-auth/core/index.js:202:38)
at async NextAuthRouteHandler (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./node_modules/next-auth/next/index.js:50:30)
at async NextAuth._args$ (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./node_modules/next-auth/next/index.js:84:24)
at async /home/alireza/Projects/moneybox/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-route.runtime.dev.js:6:61466 {
name: 'OAuthCallbackError',
code: undefined
},
providerId: 'github',
message: 'outgoing request timed out after 3500ms'
}

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.